# Mathematical expectation problem

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory, expected-value, triangle-inequality

Given: X is a random variable, $E|X|^\alpha<\infty$ with some $\alpha>0$ Prove that $E|X+b|^\alpha < \infty$ for any real b. Prove that $E|X+b|^\alpha = \infty$ if b-> $\infty$
My suggestion is triangle inequality: $E|X+b|^\alpha\leq E|X|^\alpha + E|b|^\alpha$ but I can`t prove it myself, any thoughts?

Comment: You can use that for every $x,y\ge0$, $(x+y)^\alpha\le2^{\alpha-1}(x^\alpha+y^\alpha)$ if $\alpha\ge1$ and $(x+y)^\alpha\le x^\alpha+y^\alpha$ if $0<\alpha<1$.

Comment: That is true but b can be a negative number too and so do X

Comment: Yes but you can apply $|X+b|\le|X|+|b|$ first, then $|X+b|^\alpha\le(|X|+|b|)^\alpha$ since $x\mapsto x^\alpha$ is increasing on $[0,\infty)$.